# How can I create a logger that extends log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, interface, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to migrate from log4j 1 to log4j 2.

My current logger extends `Logger` which is imported by
`org.apache.log4j.Logger`.

`Logger` is a class which doesn't exist in log4j2.

In Log4j2 we have
`org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` which is an interface and in order to implement it, I'll have to implement lots of methods of this interface, which I don't want to.

Other option is to extend `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` which is a class but have entire different methods set and doesn't really return or create a `Logger` type class.

I mean that if i'll write

```
public final class MyLogger extends LogManager {
```

I'll limit my logger to LogManager instance instead of Logger instance.

**My current code is:**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    
    
    /**
     * The Class MyLogger.
     */
    public final class MyLogger extends Logger {
    
        /** The logger instance. */
        private Logger loggerInstance = null;
    
        /** The MyLogger logger. */
        private static MyLogger myLogger = null;
    
        /**
         * Instantiates a MyLogger logger.
         */
        private MyLogger() {
            super("MyLogger");
        }
    
        /**
         * Gets the logger.
         *
         * @param clazz - The Class
         * @return the logger
         */
        public static MyLogger getLogger(Class clazz) {
            myLogger = new MyLogger();
            myLogger.setLoggerInstance(Logger.getLogger(clazz));
            return myLogger;
    }
```

I've managed to re-write

```
private MyLogger() {
        super("MyLogger");
    }
```

to

```
private MyLogger() {
        getLogger("MyLogger");
    }
```

which calls the `getLogger` method inside the extended class `LogManager`.

but I don't know how to re-write

```
public static MyLogger getLogger(Class clazz) {
                myLogger = new MyLogger();
                myLogger.setLoggerInstance(Logger.getLogger(clazz));
                return myLogger;
        }
```

and other methods that I wrote to override:

```
/**
     * Warn.
     *
     * @param message the message
     */
    @Override
    public void warn(Object message) {

        loggerInstance.warn(message);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the logger instance.
     *
     * @return the logger instance
     */
    public Logger getLoggerInstance() {
        return loggerInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the logger instance.
     *
     * @param loggerInstance the new logger instance
     */
    public void setLoggerInstance(Logger loggerInstance) {
        this.loggerInstance = loggerInstance;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try the [Log4j 1.x bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz no because I don't want to import the log4j 1.x jar at all. I mean I don't want it to be included in the compiled target jar / docker.

Comment: I am not talking about Log4j 1.x, but the [Log4j 1.x bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html), which is part of Log4j 2.x.